# How to improve this simple Brownian motion simulation by adding viscosity?

Tags: computational-physics, software, viscosity, brownian-motion

I've written a 0<sup>th</sup> order Brownian motion simulator to envision how a particle of smoke might appear to move under a microscope.

There will be missing $\sqrt{2}$'s and $\frac{\pi}{2}$'s since I haven't done proper averaging over phase space and the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution of molecule velocities in 3D.

**Question:** But my question is about viscosity. If I increase the number density, the displacement and velocity of the particles also increase *without limit*, because there's no viscosity term. How would I add viscous damping to this collision-based model? Is it possible do to so with just the mass and temperature of the air molecules and the smoke particle, and not use a "book value" for viscosity?

**hunch:** I wonder if I need to add a small $\Delta v$ to the flux $n_0 v_0$ and subtract it on the opposite side? Or do I need to handle that inside the integral over the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution, which I have avoided so far by using an average velocity.

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/430806/83380) is far too advanced for this question, and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79681/83380) not advanced enough, though it shows a nice simulation GIF and links to [here](http://weelookang.blogspot.com/2010/06/ejs-open-source-brownian-motion-gas.html) and [here](http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/ntnujava/index.php?topic=1484.).

---

At each time step I choose the momentum transfer to the smoke particle from a normal distribution with

$$\sigma_p = m_0 v_0 \sqrt{n}$$

and

$$v_0=\sqrt{k_BT/m_0},$$

$$n=n_0 v_0 A\Delta t$$

where $n$ is the number of collisions during the period $\Delta t$. $m_0$ and $m_p$ are the masses of air molecules and the smoke particle, respectively, and $A$ is the projected area of the particle.

At each step the change in the smoke particle's velocity is given by

$$dv = dp/m_p$$

At a point in time $t_j$ the velocity would be the cumulative sum of $dv \Delta T$,

$$v_j =  \Delta t \sum_{i=0}^j dv_i$$

and the position another cumulative sum of velocity:

$$x_j = \Delta t \sum_{i=0}^j v_i$$

I get plots that look plausible. Below is a 2 micron particle of porous carbon after 10,000 steps of 0.001 second each.

[image]

MORE: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySC8o.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G23kP.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoUHC.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBGUx.png), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHSsf.png), [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt1gQ.png)

Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kB = 1.381E-23
n0 = 0.02504E+27       # m^-3
m0 = 28 * 1.67E-27     # kg
T  = 293.              # K
v0 = np.sqrt(kB*T/m0)  # m/s
p0 = m0*v0

Area     = 4E-12           # m^2 (2x2 microns)
flux     = Area * n0 * v0

tstep    = 0.001
n        = flux * tstep
sigma_p  = p0 * np.sqrt(n)

N    = 10000
time = tstep*np.arange(N)
dp = np.random.normal(0, sigma_p, 3*N).reshape(3, -1)

rhop = 1000.          # kg/m^3 porous carbon
Vp   = 8E-18          # m^3 (2x2x2 microns)
mp   = rhop*Vp

dv   = dp/mp
vel  = dv.cumsum(axis=-1)  * tstep
pos  = vel.cumsum(axis=-1) * tstep

def squareax(ax):
    (xmin, xmax), (ymin, ymax) = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
    xc, yc = 0.5*(xmax+xmin), 0.5*(ymax+ymin)
    xw, yw =      xmax-xmin,       ymax-ymin
    hw     = 1.1 * 0.5 * max(xw, yw)

if True:
    fig = plt.figure()
    velplt, posplt = 1000.*vel, 1000.*pos

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    for thing in posplt:
        ax1.plot(time, thing)
    plt.title('x, y, z (mm) vs. time (sec)') 

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
    ax2.plot(posplt[0], posplt[1])
    squareax(ax2)
    plt.title('y vs. x (mm)') 

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
    for thing in velplt:
        ax3.plot(time, thing)
    plt.title('vx, vy, vz (mm/s) vs time (sec)') 

    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
    ax4.plot(velplt[0], velplt[1])
    squareax(ax4)
    plt.title('vy vs. vx (mm/s)') 

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try not to give too complicated an answer!

You are trying to solve the Langevin equation (with no external systematic forces) which can be written,
for a single particle in 1D (or for each momentum component in 3D)
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = -\xi v + \sigma\dot{w}
= -\gamma p + \sigma\dot{w}
$$
where $\xi$ is usually called the friction coefficient,
or alternatively one can use $\gamma=\xi/m$, the damping constant,
and they are both related to the diffusion coefficient $D$ by
$$
\xi = m\gamma = \frac{k_BT}{D}
$$
where $T$ is the temperature and $k_B$ Boltzmann's constant.

Rather than think in detail about individual collisions with air molecules,
I recommend using [Stokes' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_law)  to set $\xi=6\pi\eta R$ where
$R$ is the radius of the smoke particle,
and the ideal gas expression for the [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Gases) $\eta$ in terms of density, temperature, and gas molecule diameter (or mean free path).

The random forces here are written in terms of a time derivative of a Wiener process $\dot{w}$ and a strength term $\sigma$. Without going into the details, $\sigma$ must be related to $\gamma$ through the [fluctuation dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem),
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{2\xi k_BT}= \sqrt{2\gamma mk_BT}
$$
and $\dot{w}$ makes a lot more sense when we have integrated the equation for $dp/dt$ over a short time interval $\Delta t$. The result is
$$
p(\Delta t) = p(0)\exp(-\gamma \Delta t) + \sqrt{1-\exp(-2\gamma \Delta t)} \sqrt{m k_B T} \, R
$$
$R$ is a standard normally distributed random number.
You can see that it is multiplied by a factor $\sqrt{m k_B T}$
which has units of momentum.
The first term $p(0)\exp(-\gamma \Delta t)$ represents the 
mechanical effect of friction,
but you can see from the coefficient $\sqrt{1-\exp(-2\gamma \Delta t)}$
of the second term that you can't disentangle this from the
effect of the random forces.
If you allow $\gamma\rightarrow 0$,
you just get $p(\Delta t)=p(0)$ 
(the effect of the random forces also goes to zero).

Hopefully this is clear enough, and can be matched up with what you are doing in your program.

---

EDIT: just a couple of references and comments.

An early paper in this area was by 
Ermak and Buckholtz [*J Comput Phys,* **35,** 169 (1980)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(80)90084-4)
and their algorithm explicitly took into account the correlations between momenta $p$ and positions $x$, as they were advanced together.
More modern algorithms are based on a splitting approach,
which makes them algebraically (and perhaps conceptually) simpler.
A comparison of several of them can be found in 
Leimkuhler and Matthews [*J Chem Phys,* **138,** 174102 (2013)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4802990)
and their algorithm of choice "BAOAB" is mentioned in the open access paper by Shang et al 
[*Soft Matter,* **13,** 8565 (2017)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c7sm01526g).
All these methods work when there are also systematic (or external) forces,
but in the case where there aren't, one step of BAOAB is simply:
\begin{align*}
x\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t\big) &= x(0) + \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t\, p(0)/m
\\
p(\Delta t) &= p(0)\exp(-\gamma \Delta t) + \sqrt{1-\exp(-2\gamma \Delta t)} \sqrt{m k_B T} \, R
\\
x(\Delta t) &= x\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t\big) + \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t\, p(\Delta t)/m
\end{align*}

Comment: [Why doesn't the diffusivity of a particle in a fluid depend on the particle's density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468045/83380)

Comment: [Is there an expression for “rotational diffusivity”; an orientation analog to the random motion of a particle's position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470027/83380)